# How to remove SKU column from order details in My account page

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account, sku, remove

I wish to remove SKU from order details.

1. Open my account page in frontend
   2.Go to My Orders
   3.Click View Orders link from the list of orders

[image]

How to remove the SKU colum and its associated details.

Please provid eme a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need to override two phtml files,

```
module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items.phtml
module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Overide Into following path,

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items.phtml
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```